# Aligning buttons in column in Red

Tags: red

I am brand new to Red/Rebol. I love it so far, I am experimenting with the GUI system.

I am trying to align some buttons in a vertical column so to speak.

This is what I have so far

```
    Red [ Title: "Editor"  needs: 'view]

    view [ size 800x600 title "Save Notes"
    t: text  ""
    a: area 500x500 black
    button "Click" [t/text: "Red is good !" ]  return
    text "" button "Close" [quit] return
    text "" button "Save" [save %notes.dat a/text t/text "Saved"]
        ]
```

This is what it creates, which I have annotated with what I am trying to do: 
[image]

Comment: Nice explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Red!

In the [VID](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html) dialect, the default direction where the next element will be put, is by default horizontal (`across`), so that a `return` will go to the next column. If you switch the direction to vertical (using `below`), then the next element will go in the next row, staying in the same column. So it gives you:

```
Red [ Title: "Editor"  needs: 'view]

view [ size 800x600 title "Save Notes"
    t: text  ""
    a: area 500x500 black
    below pad 10x0
    button "Click" [t/text: "Red is good !" ] 
    text "hello" button "Close" [quit]
    text "world" button "Save" [save %notes.dat a/text t/text "Saved"]
]
```

*Note: I just put some text into your empty labels, so that we can see them in the layout, and how they affect the positionning of the buttons.*

Have fun playing with it! ;-)